# How to execute complex shell expressions in Ansible?

Tags: ruby, bash, ansible

I am creating an Ansible playbook and need to install a Ruby gem (`jekyll`) only if it is not already installed.  These work for me when run on the command line on the target host (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
gem list  | grep "jekyll " > /dev/null  || gem install jekyll
(gem list | grep "jekyll " > /dev/null) || gem install jekyll
```

That is, when the gem has already been installed, it will not be installed again.  However, when I put these commands in an Ansible playbook the gem is always installed:

```
- name: Install Jekyll only if not yet installed
  shell: (gem list | grep "jekyll " > /dev/null) || gem install jekyll
```

What do I need to do to get this to work?  Does it need escaping of some kind?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the [gem](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/gem_module.html) module?

Comment: Well now I feel really dumb, I forgot that there is a gem module...however, I would still like to know why the expression didn't work.

Comment: My guess would be the escaping and possibly the 'continue if false' (`||`).  However, you can test that theory by putting your command in a shell script and sending the shell script.  The other option would be to remove the check and use `shell: gem install jekyll` with a `creates:` argument to check whether the gem exists in the library.

Comment: Take a look at Ruby's built-in [Shell](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/shell/rdoc/index.html) and [ShellWords](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) classes. You might find them useful.

Comment: I just found that using the `gem` module did not work!  It installed the `jekyll` executable in `/root/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin` (I'm running as root), but that directory was not put in the path.  In contrast, when I run the `gem` command directly on the command line, it puts that executable in `/usr/local/bin`, so it can be accessed.  I could of course add the Ruby dir to my path, but then it would need to change when upgrading Ruby, unless I use a symlink like `current`.

Comment: @theTinMan I've used those classes before.  I looked to see what it would do and tried escaping the double quotes.  Still no joy.  @Theo Thank you, the `creates:` approach worked for me when I tested for `/usr/local/bin/jekyll`...I'd still like to use the result of `gem list` though, I think it's more reliable.  Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: shouldn't it be `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: @KeithBennett, I think I found a solution to get and check against the gem list.  Posting as answer.

Comment: @Guido No, if the gem exists, then grep will return 0, and the expression will be evaluated as true.  In this case I do *not* want the right side expression (the `gem install`) to be evaluated/executed.

Answer (score 1):

While I favor using the [gem](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/gem_module.html) module, the script could be split into two tasks.

Add an extra task prior to checking for the gem that pulls the gem list (stripping off the versions), then use a conditional to only run when the gem does not exist.

```
  - name: Get Gem List
    shell: gem list | awk '{print $1}'
    register: gem_list

  - name: Install jekyll jekyll
    shell: gem install jekyll
    when: "'jekyll' not in gem_list.stdout_lines"
```

Comment: Could we do the conversion to boolean value in the 1st task?  Is there something we can do in the shell command to convert the presence or absence of the string into a boolean, named for example, `jekyll_present`? And use the exit code of `gem list | grep` rather than stdout?

Comment: Maybe something like `gem list | grep "jekyll " == "jekyll "`?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I was using `stdout` as well.  Also, I tried the `==` approach and get a parse error.

Comment: I have incorporated your solution into my playbook, and it works.  I liked the `creates:` approach but realized the creates approach is not as accurate, especially since `gem uninstall` explicitly offers the option of not deleting the executable.  I've upvoted your answer and all your comments but have not marked the question answered because I'm still curious how I could have done it in 1 task using boolean logic.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's an environment issue.

Try to use

```
bash -lc "gem install ..."
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO isn't a discussion board, instead it's an online reference book, like a cookbook of programming problems and solutions. As such it's not necessary, nor is it desirable to use salutations, valedictions or signatures in questions or answers, just as if the questions and answers were in an encyclopedia or programming book.

Comment: This did not work for me, but thank you for the suggestion.  This has become a yak shaving adventure for me, I've already posted an issue on the Ansible Github site at https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/3903, but I need to move on now.  Thanks...